# UI Bootstrap Carousel (with Bootstrap 2.3.2) not working when hide and show in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I´m trying to use a Bootstrap 2.3.2 Carousel to display an item pictures. The user can get a list of items. When he clicks on a concrete item, some detailed info is displayed in the same view. The moment the user clicks on the same item again, the info is hidden (more or less like on an accordion, just to make you understand). Part of these detailed info is a carousel with the item photos.

When I first click on an item, the carousel is working perfectly. It is loaded. The pictures are displayed, and it iterates over the pictures.

However, when I click to hide the details, and click to show again, the carousel doesn´t work anymore. I can inspect the data, and I see the pictures info is there. However, nothing is shown.

I know it is quite difficult to find out the cause of the problem without code, but I have tried to reproduce the same scenario in a plunker, but I´m not able to do it. In my plunker is working.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE:**

My carousel code:

```
<div class="row-fluid info-section">
        <div class="span12">
            boatSelected.mainPhoto={{boatSelected.mainPhoto | json}}
            boatPhotos={{boatPhotos | json}}
            <img src="img/nophoto.jpg" ng-hide="boatSelected.mainPhoto">
            <div id="boatCarousel" class="carousel slide" ng-show="boatSelected.mainPhoto">
                <carousel interval="30000">
                    <slide ng-repeat="boatPhoto in boatPhotos">
                        <img src="//{{S3_BUCKET}}.{{PHOTO_SERVER_URL}}/img/boats/{{boatSelected.id}}/{{boatPhoto.id}}.{{boatPhoto.mime}}" style="margin:auto;">
                    </slide>
                </carousel>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**UPDATE**
I have to apologize for the confusion. According to the colleagues comments, I have reviewed the code, and I have realized I´m not working with Bootstrap 2.3.2 Carousel, but as you can see in the code above, I´m working with UI Bootstrap Carousel directive that I already integrated. But, the problem is still the same. It´s not working in the scenario depicted above.

**UPDATE 2:**

I´m getting completely crazy with this. I have updated the plunker with some more detailed code. NOTE: The carousel is not working in Plunker (in my application, first time it´s working perfectly). Maybe when it works, I will be able to reproduce the issue. The point is, each time I click on a boat, some functions in controller are called. After first time, it doesn´t display the carousel anymore, however, the data are there.

http://plnkr.co/edit/OzZmlCNT7M5MeT5EANy5?p=preview

Comment: Consider switching to http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: Hi, please see my new plunker updated with some more details http://plnkr.co/edit/OzZmlCNT7M5MeT5EANy5?p=preview

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26262069/ui-bootstrap-0-6-0-carousel-not-working-when-the-slide-images-are-changed-dynami

Answer (score 0):

No jQuery (Bootstrap or other JS) plugins will work correctly with Angular without wrapping them in a directive. That's because the DOM is being torn down and recreated and jQuery plugins don't know about this, so they don't know when to run.

A directive solves this using a post-compile hook called a "link function". You'll have to learn how to create a directive, or find one that's made already, in order for other JS plugins to work correctly. Think of the link function similarly to jQuery's `$(document).ready()` function.

Comment: This was my first guess... I was using a jquery script to run my carousel, but I have realized, I don´t need it. So, I´m just using the code I update above. This is actually a directive, right? So, this is where I´m getting lost. Do I need to wrap a directive in my custom directive?

Comment: Where did carousel tag come from? A library like this? http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-carousel that's an angular directive. If it's successfully included in your project and you're using it, then you don't need any jQuery code at all and it should work as the module documentation describes it.

Comment: Going to need to see more code to tell you what's wrong. See if you can replicate your issue in a plnkr.

Comment: Please, see my new plunker updated with some more details http://plnkr.co/edit/OzZmlCNT7M5MeT5EANy5?p=preview